# Apple Push notification script not working

Tags: notifications, push

I am using this php script but its producing output **Message successfully delivered** but not sending notification. i have already check device id and certificates they are perfect and working fine with another script.

```
<?php
    // Put your device token here (without spaces):
    $deviceToken = 'fbf04bf4ace2f1e823016082da3a798cf3ab666ae99a395b65e364eb4c6d6d4a';

    // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = '123';

    // Put your alert message here:
    $message = 'A push notification has been sent!';

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'key.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => array('body' => $message, 'action-loc-key' => 'Look', ), 'badge' => 2, 'sound' => 'oven.caf', );

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    echo "<pre>Result : ";
    print_r($result);
    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Can any one help me to getting out of this.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow this link. may be this will help you to figure out the problem. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Thanks, But Ali Hafizji focus of Apple Device end...
He having no idea about Server side..

Comment: Why not try this === https://packagist.org/packages/sly/notification-pusher, its definitely worked as I just did.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar problem when i first start iOS push notifications

There Will be possibility that you are doing a development push rather than a production push
Change the server to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 and use your development push notification key to give a try.

That solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to `change port number`

You code:  `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195.` `2195` use for sandbox and `2196` use for live.

Can you please change it and try.

Hope this work.